# I am trying to write unittest for query

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I would like to ask you because I am writing a unittest for a function. The problem is the function contains for loop and in for there is sth like:

```
test = s.mod.Something 
q = s.query(test).filter(test.id == t.id).first()
```

When I use in my test sth like this s.query().filter().first().test_part = 'Z' then it works but I need to change my value in the loop and I am stuck. Do you have any suggestion how I can work with this kind of query in for loop? When I iterate sth in the loop I would like to see for:

1. first iteration s.query().filter().first().test_part = 'Z'
2. second iteratin s.query().filter().first().test_part = 'X'

Now I always see s.query().filter().first().test_part = 'Z'

my unittest looks like:

```
def test():
    m = mock.Mock()
    m.query().filter().first().test_part_x.side_effect = ['Z', 'X']
    m.query().filter().first().test_part = m.query().filter().first().test_part_x()
...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more context like the current function and unittest you have written, without them, there is not much SO can help with.